# Quicksort in javascript performance

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

```
function qsort(a) {
    if (a.length == 0) return [];
    var left = [], right = [], pivot = a[0];

    for (var i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] < pivot ? left.push(a[i]) : right.push(a[i]);
    }

    return qsort(left).concat(pivot, qsort(right));
}
```

Why is the above **QuickSort** algorithm so much **slower** than the native array.sort() method?

```
var array = Array.from({
         length: 100000
 }, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
```

---

```
array.slice(0).sort((a,b) => a-b); // 34ms
```

---

```
qsort(array) // 2436ms
```

Comment: the built-in `sort` uses no new arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the native method does not create and mutate arrays in a recursive way in javascript.

Comment: Ok thanks. But why is this version of mergesort a lot faster than the native? It uses recursion and creates new arrays.https://github.com/senner007/mergeSort/blob/master/main.js